# how can i delete div using for loop with delay 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, for-loop

I would like to delete group of div. All the div tag's class="mt1" I can delete first item. But i would like to do it all with 5 second delay.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="mgroup">
   <div class="mt1">Text 1</div> // wait 5 second and delete
   <div class="mt1">Text 2</div> // wait 5 second and delete
   <div class="mt1">Text 3</div> // wait 5 second and delete
   <div class="mt1">Text 4</div> // wait 5 second and delete
   <div class="mt1">Text 5</div> // wait 5 second and delete
</div>
```

**My JS Code:**

```
var div = $('.mt1');
if(div.lenght >0)
{
   var parent = div.first();
   parent.fadeOut("fast", function(){ parent.remove(); } );
}
```

My code deletes first item of div. I want it to repeat it every 5 seconds. Any suggestion?

Comment: `div.lenght` won't work, spelling matters in programming

Comment: well, this code works fine deletes first item of div named class="mt1"  ?

Comment: Only by accident - the `.lenght` property will be `undefined`

Comment: @CertainPerformance okay, i will be careful about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have a recursive function that takes the index of the element to fade out, and fades it out if it exists, calling itself again with the next `i`. Use `div.eq(i)` to select the `i`th child:

```js
const fadeOutNext = (i) => {
  var div = $('.mt1');
  if (!div[i]) {
    return;
  }
  div.eq(i).fadeOut("fast", function() {
    setTimeout(fadeOutNext, 5000, i + 1);
  });
};

fadeOutNext(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mgroup">
  <div class="mt1">Text 1</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 2</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 3</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 4</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 5</div> // wait 5 second and delete
</div>
```

If the elements don't need to exist in the DOM anymore after being faded out, you can `.remove()` to make the code nicer:

```js
const fadeOutNext = () => {
  var div = $('.mt1');
  if (!div.length) {
    return;
  }
  div.eq(0).fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    setTimeout(fadeOutNext, 5000);
  });
};

fadeOutNext();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mgroup">
  <div class="mt1">Text 1</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 2</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 3</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 4</div> // wait 5 second and delete
  <div class="mt1">Text 5</div> // wait 5 second and delete
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks. i am learning js yet.. this example was a little bit complicated for me. Cheers.

Comment: so, there is one more question about timing. It's deleting first item so fast. Do we need second settimeout before .remove()?

Comment: The problem is that the browser engine is busy loading the page, and immediately when the page is loaded, the first element gets removed, so it's hard to see. If this removal occurs anytime *other* than on pageload, it won't be an issue. If it *does* need to occur on pageload, then I guess you could put the initial `fadeOutNext` in a `setTimeout`, eg `setTimeout(fadeOutNext, 1000)` so that the first fadeout happens 1000ms after the page is loaded

Comment: well, i just tried  setTimeout(function() { your code }, 2000); and it worked. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let child = 0;

setInterval(()=>{

const c = $('.mt1:nth-child('+child+')');
c.fadeOut("fast", function(){ c.remove(); } );

child++;

},5000);
```

Comment: hey, i have tried this too. it deletes first and third one. Answer is already marked but if you fix your answer that will be a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for setInterval:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var div = $('.mt1').first()
    div[0] ? div.fadeOut("fast", function(){ div.remove() } ) : clearInterval(interval)
}, 5000)
```